# Angular JS filter giving 'notArray' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm getting data from my local PHP file as JSON format (here's a screenshot).

[image]

The filter works fine, but I'm getting this error as you can see in the pic.

core.js

```
var app = angular.module('cnrapp', []);

app.controller('listController', function($http) {
var vm = this;

vm.loading = true;
vm.players = {};

$http.get("api/players.php")
    .then(function (res) {

        var s1 = res.data.servers[0].players;
        var s2 = res.data.servers[1].players;

        vm.players = s1.concat(s2);
        vm.loading = false;
        console.log(vm.players);
    });
});
```

index.html

```
<li ng-repeat="player in vm.players | filter: search">
    <a href="#">{{ player.name }}</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should initialize players as an array and not as an object:

```
vm.players = [];
```

Comment: You mean that's empty after the line vm.players = s1.concat(s2) ?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

This is an object:

```
vm.players = {};
```

You can insert only `Object` in above variable, not an `array` of `Object`. To insert an `array` of `Object`s, you need:

```
vm.players = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define your array like this:

```
vm.loading = true;
vm.players = [];
```

Not with curly brackets.